# Working out the point on a circle using another point and the angle between them

Tags: c++, sfml, trigonometry

I have a point on a circle with center (0, 0), called (x1, y1), and an angle called A (in degrees). I want to find a function which lets me find another point on the circle (x2, y2), like this:
 [image: Diagram]

I have a function which looks like this (I am using c++ sfml)

```
//sf::Vector2f has two members, x and y, which are both quotes. 
sf::Vector2f findPoint(int A, sf::Vector2f x1y1) 
{
    sf::Vector2f x2y2;
    // Code I need
    return x2y2;
 }
```

Please help me find the code I need

Comment: What have you tried? What approaches have you considered? Do you know any trigonometry?

Comment: I tried something where I figure out the angle of the first point, and then add that to A, and then find out the point from the angle, but I don't know enough trig for the last step.

Comment: Plus one for the nice picture ;-) Makes my ascii matrices look pretty rubbish.

Comment: I made it on my phone, its quite poor quality :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to build a class that models a point in *both* Cartiesian *and* polar coordinates.

You can then use (x1, x2) -> to Polar -> add the angle -> to Cartesian.

Alternatively, you can use the *generalised rotation matrix*:

```
    /  \    /               \/  \ 
    |x2|  = | cos A   -sin A||x1| 
    |y2|    | sin A    cos A||y1| 
    \  /    \               /\  /
```

i.e. `x2 = y1 cos A - y1 sin A` and `y2 = x1 sin A + y1 cos A`

Comment: That doesn't seem like the easiest way.

Comment: Done it in my head already. Which bit is hard? You know that x1 = r cos T and y1 = r sin T where T is the angle between the positive x axis and the line from the origin to your point, and r is the distance of the point from the origin? You can pretty much go from there, If your feeling really smart you could use complex numbers.

Comment: Because I have to create a class that models both types of coordinates. It would be easier for me to just have one long function.

Comment: OK. Long function mathematics added.

Comment: Oh thats more useful thank you. Do you know how I can write that in C++? I'm not very well versed with matrixes

Comment: Added the formulas long hand. Note that C++ trig functions are in *radians* mode.

Comment: OK thanks a lot, I guess I didn't think about it hard enough because that's really simple. I'll give you confirmation when I test the code later today. Thank you!